# Iframe - Access information within it

Tags: javascript

I have A.com. B.com has section of the site that I want to present on A.com. B.com is some sort of quiz with questions. When the user completes the questions he will be given diploma with some values in it. I need to get those values.

I know people who made the B.com, and they promised to help in whatever way they can.  What should I tell them? What they need to do on their side, so that I can access their Iframe that contain values I need?

I have found easyXDM library that seem good candidate for my problem.
Can someone confirm this is going to do the job? 
http://easyxdm.net/wp/2010/03/17/setting-up-your-first-socket/

Comment: ask them to build an api for you and implement the quiz gui yourself.

Comment: Thing is that I dont have resources to implement it. I would rather utilize existing application